# how to synchronize Room data with Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-room

I want to be sure that I can save data offline. How to synchronize data in Room with Firestore? When something inserted to Room Firestore must be updated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore already has a persistence layer included, you don't need Room at all. You can enable the offline support like this:

```
val settings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
    .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
    .build()
db.firestoreSettings = settings
```

Using Firestore for persistance has many benefits over Room (besides the saved effort and potential bugs). If you e.g. load all restaurants in a city, then go offline and then run a query on e.g. the best restaurants the query will still work and use the cached data even when the query was never run while being online.

You can also configure the cache size Firestore uses to meet your needs. Documents are cached in a LRU manner, so the documents which were not used for the longest time get removed from the cache first once it is full.

A best practice is to always use snapshot listeners. If you start a query in offline mode and the device gets back online, Firestore will automatically run the query again with the server and return the updated result to your UI.

Check out the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) and [this video about Firestore offline mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDvdAFP6OhQ) for more details.

Comment: While what you're saying is true, it doesn't answer the question.  There are cases where the local cache isn't sufficient, and synchronization with Room is required.  For example, many apps need to be usable offline-first, and the Firestore local cache is not very good for that.

Comment: In most cases manually syncing is not the best idea. That's where my answer is coming from. If the question would contain more information about the use case, my answer might change.

Comment: Firestore offline mode is useless, there is no indexing so queries are not really working and performance is awful.

Comment: what if I already have an existing app with Room db and need to add sync feature using Google account?